# How to add Wanda (the fish) to the GNOME Shell panel?

Tags: gnome, fortune

How do you add [Wanda (the fish)](http://social.wakoopa.com/software/wanda-the-fish) to the GNOME Shell panel, or to the launcher, and have it display `fortune`? I want my fish back.

[image]

I already have `fortune`; I can just type into the terminal `fortune` and it works, but I want to add it to the left panel, using GNOME Shell.

Comment: Are you by chance referring to the `xfishtank` package?

Comment: There is an indicator for that. I will try to find it for you.

Comment: Roland: that's indicator-fish (http://launchpad.net/indicator-fish), but Gnome Shell doesn't use Ubuntu's indicators so it won't work there. Currently, there is no way to do this. Someone might make an excension; it could be fun to do, since the extensions system is really neat! :)

Comment: @DylanMcCall: They do work in GNOME-Shell; as system tray icons. **EDIT:** *Before you ask, I've tested.*

Answer (score 6):

### Indicator-fish:

You can use [indicator-fish](https://launchpad.net/indicator-fish). It is packaged for 11.04, so if you add the PPA, edit the source entry to point to "Natty". Or, you can build from source, or download the package from the PPA manually. It works in Unity and GNOME Shell.

### An example of what it says:

> [image: You are confused; but this is your normal state.]
>   (*It really is isn't it?*)

Comment: lol is this omg. Thanks a lot, i will install it :)

Comment: Yay! I thought the systray fallback was broken for some reason. Nice to know it works. I just uploaded a new version for 11.10, so it should be published in an hour or so. Have fun :)

Comment: @DylanMcCall: I'll edit my answer soon to reflect the changes :)

Comment: @DylanMcCall and Roland Taylor thanks a lot, now i will report a little error, if u type indicator-fish inside the terminal, that work but when close that terminal you kill wanda , but if you press ALT+F2 and write indicator-fish, work amazing.  I will report few issues to indicator-fish launchpad site.Working from the ppa.

Comment: @MarceloKobs: that's not an issue. You have to run it as either `nohup indicator-fish` or `indicator-fish & disown` or install grun and run `grun indicator-fish`. Terminals are not supposed to detach from the application by default, so if you close it, you close the application.

Comment: @MarceloKobs: BTW, remember to mark the question as solved by clicking the tick next to my answer :)!

Answer (score 2):

This will be supported officially in the next version of gnome (gnome 3.4):

https://live.gnome.org/ThreePointThree/ReleaseNotes#GNOME_3.4

Comment: And [here is a direct link](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell/commit/?id=50aa15dec9c64d6b08fc863bdb909ab07438c110) to the actual commit which made this possible.